# Elasticsearch template not working as intended

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

So I have an elasticsearch template that I'm passing in to ES via Filebeat.   I have Filebeat sending to logstash as well... here's the relevant stuff.

**Elasticsearch template**

```
{
"template": "filebeat-*",
"mappings": {
    "product__name": {
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "@version": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "beat": {
                "properties": {
                    "hostname": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "class_method": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "class_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true",
                "fielddata": "true"
            },
            "clientip": {
                "type": "ip"
            },
            "count": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "host": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "input_type": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "log_level": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "log_message": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "log_timestamp": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "log_ts": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "offset": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "query_params": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "sessionid": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "source": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "thread": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "user_account_combo": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "version": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    },
    "access": {
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "@version": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "beat": {
                "properties": {
                    "hostname": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "clientip": {
                "type": "ip"
            },
            "count": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "host": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "input_type": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "log_timestamp": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "log_ts": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "message": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "offset": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "query_params": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "response_time": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "sessionid": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "source": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "statuscode": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "tags": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "thread": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "uripath": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "user_account_combo": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            },
            "verb": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata": "true",
                "index": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**filebeat config** (trimmed)

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["10.10.43.210:9200"]
  template:
    name: filebeat
    path: "test-template.json"
    overwrite: true

output.logstash:
    hosts: ["10.10.43.210:5044"]
    worker: 2
    index: filebeat
```

**Logstash Config** (Trimmed)

```
output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
```

And lastly... here's what shows up in Kibana:

[image: Kibana fields]

So the question is:  Why am I seeing .keyword fields on things when I've been pretty explicit about what types I want everything to be and not letting logstash overwrite my template?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana 5.x generates the `.keyword` field for all `string` typed fields. This allows you to do aggregations based on the entire field. For example if you wanted to do a count of the unique values of your `host` field, you would perform the aggregation on `host.keyword`.

So this behavior does not mean your template is being overwritten, it is intentional behavior from Kibana allowing you to do aggregations on string fields. If you want to check if your template is being overwritten by Logstash somehow, check in Elasticsearch with 
`curl elasticsearch:9200/{template_name}?pretty` which will show your index mapping. This can help you verify that your index is using the mapping you expect.

Comment: But they're not strings, I call them out specifically as text / keyword fields as they are needed.  Why are they generating both for each of these fields

Comment: Kibana calls text/keyword typed fields 'string', just as it calls int/long 'number'. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-fields.html) is some documentation regarding Kibana field formats.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent it from casting these to both?  I'd rather save the processing power / memory for other tasks.

Comment: It isn't _casting_ them necessarily, it just groups the Elasticsearch data types into those four (number, string, date, geopoint) to determine which types of aggregations can be applied in Kibana.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the `.keyword` field in Kibana, you can change your mapping from type `text` to type `keyword`, but that means that those fields will only be searchable by exact value. Otherwise as far as I know, Kibana will always add that `.keyword` field by default to all fields with a `text` mapping to allow for aggregations.